# use single-sign-on/remote-user authentication with django restframework to get authentication token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on

I have a django application implementing a REST API using the django-rest-framework.
The authentication is to be implementated using apache/single-sign-on/remote-user method, for the non-API part of the URL Tree.
and for the API portion of the tree we would like to use token based authentication.

What is the simplest way to retrieve the authentication token, through a restframework APIview under the non-SSO protected part of the URL subtree.
Using rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token seems to look for user/password in the json data.

What is the best way of doing this using single-sing-on/remote_user, where the authentication is taken care of the apache.

I was thiking there should be an existing authentication class that should help. But can't seem to find it.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?